# Repeat loop from beginning until new numbers breaks and loop again in c

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops, break

so I'm confused about how to solve this problem in C. The answer to this question is more likely solve if I can understand the logic. But it seems I cant understand it. Sorry if the question title does not matches the explanation of the problem. So:

In C, loop with using for like this, `for(x=0;x<10;x++)`
, this will result to loop simultaneously without a break.
For example:

```
for(x=0;x<10;x++)
printf("this is x = %d",x);
```

result example:

```
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
.
.
this is x = 10
```

So how to loop, but will break in each new number and start over then break/pause until new numbers and so on. For example:

```
for(x=0;x<//variables;x++)
printf("this is x = %d",x);
```

result:

```
(start)
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
(over/break)

(start)
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
(over/break)

(start)
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 3
(over/break)

.
.
.

(start)
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 3
.
.
.
this is x = 10
(over/break)
```

So how to do this? This maybe seems simple but I can't find the solution. I hope the explanation can make the problem clear. Thank you.

Comment: With `x < 10` in the condition, the last line you print should be with `x == 9`.  Ignoring that detail, it looks like you want a nested loop like `for(int max = 2; max < 10; max += 1) { for (int x = 0; x < max; x += 1) {...} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use nested for loops as for example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
    for ( int x = 0; x  <= i + 1; ++x )
    {
        printf( "this is x = %d\n", x );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        for ( int x = 0; x  <= i + 1; ++x )
        {
            printf( "this is x = %d\n", x );
        }
    }    
}
```

Its output is

```
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 3
this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 3
this is x = 4
```

and so on.

If you want to separate outputs with a blank line like

```
this is x = 0
this is x = 1

this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2

this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 3

this is x = 0
this is x = 1
this is x = 2
this is x = 3
this is x = 4
...
```

then write the loops like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
    for ( int x = 0; x  <= i + 1; ++x )
    {
        printf( "this is x = %d\n", x );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

If you want to use only one for loop then the program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    for ( int x = 0, i = x + 1;  i <= 10;  )
    {
        printf( "this is x = %d\n", x );
        if ( x == i )
        {
            putchar( '\n' );
            ++i;
            x = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++x;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just us 2 for loops instead of 1:

```c
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < y; x++)
        printf("this is x = %d",x);
```

If you wan't to change the maximum number, just change the value in the condition of the first loop (`y < 10`).

Answer (score 0):

two loops, the outer one increments the maximum number to count up to for the inner loop.